# How to use rendering result of scene as texture in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I would like to use the rendering result of the scene as a texture in ThreeJS.
Does ThreeJS have such a function?
Do I need to modify ThreeJS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render a scene to a texture by passing a [**`THREE.WebGLRenderTarget`**](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) to `THREE.WebGLRenderer.render()`.

First, create a **render target** of the desired size (this is your texture) :

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(512, 512);
```

You can then use `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget.texture` on a material :

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1.0, 1.0);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: renderTarget.texture
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Finally render the scene in 2 passes :

```
renderer.render(fakeScene, fakeCamera, renderTarget);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

You may want to create a new scene and a new camera to render on the `renderTarget`. It depends on what you want to do.

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8fmkw96/) and [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html).

Comment: Certainly it was done.
I can use scenes as textures using renderTarget.
It was easy and easy to understand.
Thank you very much.